# Refactor useHistory state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm using useHistory to route my website from page A

```
const history = useHistory();
history.push('/this/is/page-b', { object: selectedObject });
```

and in page B, I have:

```
const history = useHistory();
const objectData = history.location?.state?.object as Object;
```

- First question: Is there anything wrong with this code? Trying to pass data using history.
- Second question: Any suggestion for another solution to pass data instead of via useHistory hook? Just need some keywords.
  Thank guys.

Answer (score 1):

In react router 6, use `useNavigate`

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/this/is/page-b', { object: selectedObject });
```

use `useLocation` to catch data

```
const {object} = useLocation();
```

Comment: Yah, I see this, but I'm using react-router-v5 :(

Comment: can still use `useLocation` with the history push

Comment: `history.push({ pathname: '/this/is/page-b', state: selectedObject,         });`

Comment: access data from component prop. like `props.location.state`